# 'printf' outputting garbage instead of specific characters

Tags: c, memory, printf

Well, I've a weird problem with `printf()`. It's outputting garbage on the screen. It's kind of connected with memory, I guess. Have a look:

```
char string1[] = "SAMPLE STRING";
char string2[20]; // Some garbage in it

/* Let's clear this madness*/
int i = 0;
for (i; i < 20; i++) string2[i] = ' ';   // Space, why not?

printf("output: %s", string2);
```

#### Output

```
output:      ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠SAMPLE STRING
// Ten spaces and random characters, why?
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not *20* spaces and then random characters after that?

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437, and [MSVC fills 0xCC to uninitialized memory to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). That means you've accessed uninitialized memory. You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because C strings need to be NUL terminated. This means the last char of your string must be `'\0'`. This is how `printf` (and all other C string functions) know when a string is finished.

Comment: Actually, they are NUL terminated. NUL is the nul character, NULL is the nul pointer.

Comment: I would write this as "null-terminated", not "NULL terminated", since `NULL` (all caps) is a pointer, so it could be confusing.

Comment: *[null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)*

Answer (score 2):

Finish your `string2` with a null character, `'\0'`:

```
string2[19] = '\0';
```

Or you can do it in this way:

```
for (i; i < 19; i++)
    string2[i] = ' ';
string2[i] = '\0'; // After the end of the loop, i=19 here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string1[] = "SAMPLE STRING";

    // Using curly braces {} for initialization
    char string2[20] = {}; // Initialize all elements to 0 (null)

    printf("Using curly braces initialization:\n");
    printf("output: %s\n\n", string2);

    // Using designated initializer for spaces and null-terminator
    char string3[20] = {[0 ... 18] = ' '}; // Initialize elements 0 to 18 with spaces

    printf("Using designated initializer for spaces:\n");
    printf("output: %s\n\n", string3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The empty braces intitializer `{}` has been illegal in standard C until the upcoming C23 where it will finally be in the language (some compilers support it, but it is not portable). Using ranges, e.g., `[0 ... 18]` is not legal in standard C either; this is a Gnu C extension.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76923766/edit), not here in comments (and *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Information about what compiler (incl. version and compiler options) in what environment was used to test this could also be useful.

Comment: Has the code been generated by some tool? Which one?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).